# What happens after an assignment to the reference and the memory?

Tags: c#, binary-tree, reference-type

I came across a `Remove()` function that doesn't seem right to me .  We have 2 variables `obj1` and `obj2`.  Both are from the same class.

```
public class BinayTree<T> (){
  public T value;
  public BinayTree<T> parent;
  public BinayTree<T> leftChild;
  public BinayTree<T> rightChild;
}
```

if we say

```
obj1.value = obj2.value;
obj1 = obj2;
```

would this happen:

[image: my thoughts]

or this:

[image: what it says in the book]

and what exactly happens to the memory?

Comment: I don't understand what is being asked here.

Comment: What is wrong with `Remove`?

Comment: Inside the memory, variable `obj1` will now point to the same instance of `BinayTree` as variable `obj2`.

Comment: First statement effect depends on whether its a reference type or value type.

Comment: If it's value type it copies the value from object2 to object1 and then object1 points to object2. If there are no objects in the memory pointing to original location which object1 was pointing, then GC will reclaim that memory.

Comment: should i screenshot you the code ? In short the Remove() function whants to replace the value of obj1 with obj2 while not replacing the leftChild and rightChild and the parent of obj1 and delete  obj2 .

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake myself the BinaryTree class is IComparable<T>.What will happen if the Tree is from type int  and we say obj1 = obj 2 ?

Comment: Your diagrams are confusing because you seem to be identifying the objects and the variables that hold references to them with the same identifiers. Object instances don't have an identifier, they have a reference.

Comment: i was trying to make the same objects with diffrent colors for diffrent value but i gues that was not the right choice

Comment: Since you appear to find visualizations helpful, I suggest reading over http://www.leerichardson.com/2007/01/parameter-passing-in-c.html .  It offers similar diagrams.

Answer (score 1):

I hope the figures help you understand what exactly is happening.

**Step 1 - Initializing the objects**

```
var obj1 = new BinaryTree<int>();
obj1.Value = 123;

var obj2 = new BinartyTree<int>();
obj2.Value = 456;
```

We have created two objects in memory, each one assigned to a particular variable. For the sake of example, let's assume they are found in memory locations **333** and **555**:

```
 obj1                     obj2             
   |                        |              
   |                        |              
   |                        |              
   V                        V              
 _____________            _____________     
|   #333      |          |   #555      |  
|_____________|          |_____________|      
|             |          |             |    
| Value: 123  |          | Value: 456  |     
|             |          |             |     
|_____________|          |_____________|
```

---

**Step 2 - Changing a value**

Here, we are **changing the value** of a property in the object that `obj1` is referring to.

```
obj1.value = obj2.value;
```

The **value** of the `Value` field in `obj1` is changed:

```
 obj1                     obj2             
   |                        |              
   |                        |              
   |                        |              
   V                        V              
 _____________            _____________     
|   #333      |          |   #555      |  
|_____________|          |_____________|      
|             |          |             |    
| Value: 456  |          | Value: 456  |     
|             |          |             |     
|_____________|          |_____________|
```

---

**Step 3 - Changing a reference**

```
obj1 = obj2;
```

Here, we are changing **the reference to the object** that `obj1` points to.

```
 obj1                     obj2             
    \__                     |              
        \__                 |              
            \__             |              
                \__         V              
 _____________      \__   _____________     
|   #333      |       _\||   #555      |  
|_____________|          |_____________|      
|             |          |             |    
| Value: 456  |          | Value: 456  |     
|             |          |             |     
|_____________|          |_____________|
```

We did not change the value of any of the objects. We merely changed **which** object that `obj1` points to.

---

Based on your question, I can see that you are expecting the code to implicitly **link** the two objects to each other.

Think of it this way: if your expectation was the case, then we wouldn't need classes like `BinaryTree<T>` with inner references to other `BinaryTree<T>` objects.

The existence of your example class proves that your expectations are not the case.

---

**Edit**

My example assumes that `T` in `BinaryTree<T>` is a **value type**. If this is a **reference** type (e.g. a custom class you created), then step 2 gets a lot hairier. I don't think I could adequately draw that with my limited ASCII art skills.

Without trying to offend, there is a clear discrepancy between your grasp on the basics of reference type assignment and the complexity of the example code that you posted.

You are currently struggling with the basics of reference type variables. I suggest to brush up on the basics *before* you try to tackle generic classes with reference type arguments; as this is going to get massively more complicated without understanding how reference type assignment works.

Comment: If we want obj1 to get the value of obj2 and we want to delete obj2 we need to say this right ?     `obj1.value = obj2.value;    obj2 = null;` So after the first line obj1 is pointing to the same object as obj2 and after the 2nd obj2 is not pointing anywhere

Comment: @NikolaiKolev: If I understand you correctly; yes that it correct. However, your phrasing is often ambiguous. E.g. when you say "delete obj2", you could be referring to from memory (a) removing the object that obj2 is referring to (b) removing the reference in obj2 that points towards this particular object or (c) somehow implying that a variable itself can be deleted. Semantically, (c) is most correct, (a) is the second most correct (semantically in English); but you likely _intend_ to talk about (b). This sort of ambiguity is causing a lot of issues with the readability of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Since they are object instances, they are reference typed. And by the time you do this assignement:

```
obj1 = obj2;
```

The variable `obj1` will reference the same object in `obj2`. They are referencing the same object data in the memory.

The object that was referenced in `obj1` before is now lost and will be cleaned in the memory by the garbage collector.

Answer (score 0):

I will tell exactly what happens, assuming `T` is a reference type.

Originally,

[image]

After first line:

[image]

After second line:

[image]

Basically what happens is:

- `obj1` and `obj2` now refers to the same object.
- The `BinaryTree` object originally referred to by `obj1` becomes inaccessible.
- an object of `T` (formerly known as `obj1.value`) becomes inaccessible.